# How can I make cookies' 'key: value' array after getting their value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, key-value

I want to create a list of cookies and their values,
after getting their value, and then set it in another place

```
var cookiesNames= ["Cookie1","Cookie2", "Cookie3"];

function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  let cvalue= [];
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        cvalue = [c.substring(name.length, c.length)];
 // I try here to create a key: value list
       cookiesList +=[cname:c.value];
    }
  }
}

//  Gets all the cookies' names from the list 
for (var key in cookiesNames) {
 getCookie(cname);
}
// exportsTest~ I use it to export the var throughout my test at my tests platform (Testim)
exportsTest.cookiesList;
```

after getting the cooking names and their values I want to set them at a different place

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

//  Sets all the cookies from the list 
for (var key in cookiesList) {
 setCookie(key,cookiesList[key],120);
}
```

am I missing something for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start by defining `cookiesList`:

```
const cookiesList = {};
```

Then replace `cookiesList +=[cname:c.value];` with:

```
cookiesList[cname] = c.value;
```

**NOTE:**

`cookiesList` is not defined and `+=[cname:c.value]`; (1) mixes array syntax with object syntax, (2) we do not add elements to an array or properties to an object that way.

Comment: First thanks for your answer,
I've added what you said,

But I get an error saying "cname is not defined"
when I run the getCookies part
Do you know what's causing that?

Comment: Please update your question with an **Updated Code** section showing your code as it stands now. Leave the current code as is.